# Caching session data

Tags: caching, hadoop

A project I am working on requires huge amounts of data to be cached so that various services can access it and operate on it (one service writes to the cache and multiple services read and operate on it). Also the data is valid for a single session only. It keeps changing and has to be reloaded for each session. May be this is a naive question. Can big data technologies like hadoop be of use here.

Comment: Can you be more specific on "huge amounts of data"? How much data is it? How many writers and readers do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Redis](http://redis.io/). It provides in-memory data structures like lists and sets. Furthermore it is possible to let saved keys [expire](http://redis.io/commands/expire) after a defined amount of time (in your case, session timeout).

Depending on the amount of data [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org) or [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) might be an option as well.